# How to create an image of the current page including user input

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am looking to improve the error logging of a web application using C# WebForms. I want to save a screenshot of what the page looked like just before the error was thrown (including what users had in the input fields). Everything I have found was just getting a copy of the page without the user input.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using HTML5/Canvas/JavaScript to take screenshots](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well , in a webform application the application it self run on the user computer/phone/tablet (usually a browser) so you cant really have access to the GUI of the user.

You got 2 options :

1.Force the user to install some sort of logging application on his device which will generate screen shots (not likely to happen), or just send you a screenshot with the bug report.

2.Log Log log
Log every error the a database/file or what ever with as many info you can.
We usually log the URL , Exception type + message , stack trace , user info , date time

Normally this is enough for us.